# How to convert Word (have equation) to PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

I have a Word file, this file have a lot of sentences and equation. I want to convert this file to PowerPoint.
I apply heading 1 and heading 2 for the sentences, and I have successful to convert to PowerPoint but the equation cannot convert.
https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Word-to-PowerPoint
Anyone can help me to solve this problem.
I am looking forward to hearing from you. Sorry if my English is not good.

```
Sub heading1()
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
With oRng.Find
    .Text = "Project"
    While .Execute
oRng.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
Wend
End With
oRng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
End Sub

Sub heading2()
Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim nextPara As Paragraph

    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If para.Style <> "Heading 1" Then
        para.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2            
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Word documents such as pictures, shapes, equations cannot be converted to PowerPoint via the method described in the article. The process is a text-only transfer.

The article you cited even points this out at the very end of the process it outlines.

You have to copy those other objects such as equations manually.